# What's the difference between "although" and "even-if"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, vocabulary

What is the difference between the following sentences:

1. You may be prevented from crossing the border, *although* you are in possession of a valid visa.
2. You may be prevented from crossing the border, *even if* you are in
   possession of a valid visa.

If they have the same meaning, in which circumstances would it  be better to use each one?

Comment: @Araucaria I do not think that the [tag:grammar] tag is **ever** useful. It should be blacklisted.

Comment: @tchrist What's your thinking?

Comment: @Araucaria http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/986

Comment: @tchrist Hmm, will ruminate.

Answer (score 3):

They have rather different meanings, depending on what counts as "meaning".

They both assert the same thing, under the same circumstances.
But their connotations are quite distinct.

***Although** you are in possession of a valid visa* ***[presupposes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuptrig.pdf)*** that you have a valid visa.
I.e, that you have a valid visa is a fact which the speaker acknowledges and cannot deny,
though the speaker says that that doesn't matter.

***Even if** you are in possession of a valid visa*, by contrast, presupposes nothing about your visa.
You may or may not have a valid visa, and the speaker says that that doesn't matter.

Comment: If having a valid visa raises your chances of being permitted to cross the frontier from 25% to 75%, that is entirely consistent with the *even if* version, but inconsistent with the proposition that having a valid visa "doesn't matter."

Comment: No, that's not a presupposition. That's an assertion. The presupposition is that you have a valid visa, not that it will make any difference. A presupposition is a proposition that must be accepted and cannot be denied, like the proposition "Bill has a brother", which is presupposed in the sentence _Bill's brother lives in Colorado_; if the presupposition were false, the sentence would be meaningless.

Comment: A very similar issue -- between one way of saying something with a presupposition, and another way without it -- [came up again today here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/187550/15299).

Answer (score 1):

They are both accurate, but they have potentially different meanings.

1) Using the one with *although* indicates, in the example given, that the person concerned is indeed in possession of a valid visa. But 'although' they have a visa they will not necessarily be able to cross.

2) The second using *even if* can also be substituted in the above case, but it can also be used where the person concerned does NOT have a valid visa. Indeed someone might say 'It is not certain you will be able to cross because you don't have a visa, and *even if* you had you might be prevented from crossing'.

Answer (score 1):

Both indicate that a valid visa is not a sufficient condition for being permitted across the border. The one with *although* assumes that the addressee indeed has a valid visa. The one with *even if* allows for that as a possibility but does not assume it.