# When using "Used To" in a sentence with two clauses, do you change the verb tense in the second clause?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjunction-reduction

I was helping a friend proofread one of her essays on the short story [The Lottery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lottery). She had written this sentence:

> I think the lottery used to have a specific reason and represent something in the society.

I changed the sentence to

> I think the lottery used to have a specific reason and **represented** something in the society.

I thought that, because 'used to' was not directly preceding 'represent', it should be changed to past tense. But after thinking on it for a while, I am just not sure. I can't seem to find a definitive answer and the question left all of my friends conflicted.

Comment: This depends on whether the lottery *represented something in society* or *used to represent something in society*.

Comment: Good point. From what I understand of her meaning, I believe she is saying that it no longer does represent anything. So, because it no longer represents something, it should be "used to represent"?

Comment: Use *used to represent* if it habitually represented something.  Use *represented* if it, well, simply represented something without any kind of duration attached to it.  Your friend probably meant the former and simply left the second *used to* out, which is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: @Anonym Okay, so, leaving out the second _used to_ is grammatical if she wanted that meaning. Thanks!

Comment: I think both forms are perfectly valid. It all depends how closely you associate the two verbs, and how "far" the meaning of ***used to*** can stretch across a lengthy first expression. In OP's example, I'd probably go for the second version (with a comma after *reason*) because the two activities *having a specific reason* and *representing something in society* are too cumbersome to "weld together" under the influence of a single instance of *used to*.

Comment: @Ethan: You are being misinformed. In certain contexts, extending the "reach" of *used to* (as required by the unmarked infinitive ***represent*** in your case) can affect the meaning. But there is no "grammatical" reason why this should oblige you to repeat ***used to*** simply to help the reader/hearer understand that was what you meant. Much depend on *how* the words are spoken anyway (consider the implications of placing stress on the word *represent* in example #1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences come from different base forms (leaving off decorations like "I think", etc):

- *It used to [[have a specific reason] and [(it used to) represent something in the society]].*

and

- *It [used to [have a specific reason]] and [(it) [represented something in the society]].*

The words in parentheses get deleted by [conjunction reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299). Either sentence will work.

The only meaning difference between them is that the first one [presupposes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuptrig.pdf) that it no longer represents anything in the society (because *used to* asserts a past affirmative and presupposes a present negative), while the second one simply asserts the past affirmative and leaves it at that.
This is rather like [the difference between *although* and *even if*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/187512/15299).